# Guarantee a positive value for $a$ when using SolveAlways

Tags: equation-solving, constraint

```
SolveAlways[y - 3 - 4*(x - 1) == a*x + b*y + c, {x, y}]
```

> `{{a -> -4, b -> 1, c -> 1}}`

But if I want to get the following instead,

> `{{a -> 4, b -> -1, c -> -1}}`

so that `a` is always positive.

I tried to use

```
SolveAlways[y - 3 - 4*(x - 1) == a*x + b*y + c && a > 0, {x, y}]
SolveAlways[{y - 3 - 4*(x - 1) == a*x + b*y + c, a > 0}, {x, y}]
```

Neither worked.

> SolveAlways::eqf: a<=0 is not a well-formed equation.

What's wrong here? Additionally, is there a way to make sure I only get **integer** answers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what the OP asked for was mathematically impossible.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `FindInstance` is capable of this when used in conjunction with `ForAll`:

```
FindInstance[{ForAll[{x, y}, y - 3 - 4*(x - 1) == a*x + b*y + c], a > 0}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {}

However, it returns an empty solution. It seems this is correct, as the suggested solution of:

> {a -> 4, b -> -1, c -> -1}

Does not actually solve the equation for all `x` and `y`:

```
Simplify[y - 3 - 4 (x - 1) == a x + b y + c /. {a -> 4, b -> -1, c -> -1}]
```

> 4 x == 1 + y

If you expect that to be a solution, perhaps you have accidentally negated something in your equation?

You can verify that `FindInstance` can find such solutions in at least some fairly simple cases by checking a simpler function:

```
FindInstance[{ForAll[{x, y}, a x + b y + c == 3 x + 2 y + 1], a > 0}, {a, b, c}]
```

> {{a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1}}

Similarly, `Integers` can be specified as a domain for `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[{ForAll[{x}, a/c x + b == 3/4 x - 1], a > 0}, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

> {{a -> 393, b -> -1, c-> 524}}

However, `FindInstance` may provide some very odd solutions (such as representing 3/4 as 393/524 above) if there are full dimensional components, and won't typically return full solution sets. You may wish to use `Reduce` for that.